# Paypal IPN test works, but I don´t get any ipn after a sandbox purchase

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

when I run an ipn test everything works great. The data gets logged into the database as I planned it.. However when I purchase a product via. the sandbox:

- money transfered
- money accepted
- **I don´t get any ipn**

The form code I use:

```
<div class="panel-footer">
    <form class="btn-block" name="_xclick" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="paypal@**.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="product name">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_number" value="3500">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="50">
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="custom" value="<?php echo $sponsored_data[$key]['user_id']; ?>::bteam::50::3500">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://**.com/paypal/ipn.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://**.com/sponsor.html">
    <input type="hidden" name="shopping_url" value="http://**.com/sponsor.html">
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-lg btn-block btn-default">BUY NOW!</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

As I said, if I run the test on this adress it works fine: `http://**.com/sponsor.html`

Is the sandbox test not sending any ipn or did I do something wrong ?

Comment: we need the sandbox business email to check for the issue
raise a ticket here www.paypal.com/mts and let me know the ticket no

Comment: @Vimal ok, here it is: 964389

Comment: the ticket # does not seem correct , let me know you sandbox email address

Comment: do you got an e-mail or something. I don´t like to post it public.